# Given four vertices and seven edges, find the number of different graphs if there are exactly two self-loops

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In Graph Theory And Its Applications by Jonathan L. Gross, there is a question as belows:

> Given a list of four vertices and a list of seven edges, show that $C_2^7$ $5^{6}$ $2^{10}$ different formal specifications are possible if there are exactly two self-loops.
> [1.1.30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs0O7.png)

My answer is $C_2^7$ $4^{2}$ $12^{5}$,
where $C_2^7$$4^{2}$ means that I take 2 edges for self-loop and there are 4 possible vertices for each self-loop. And  $12^{5}$ means there are 4 possible vertices for one endpoint of remaining edges and then 3 possible vertices for another endpoint of remaining edges.
What's wrong with my answer ? How can I solve this question? Thank you for your helps.

Comment: What are those black blobs?

Comment: Aren't formal specifications *directed* graphs?

Comment: Are parallel edges allowed? Also, type out the question instead of putting in an image.

Comment: Yes, directed graphs and parallel edges are both allowed. The answer is C(7,2)*(5^6)*(2^10) . The question is copied from a website, there are no black blobs on my physical book.